# Cross-platform JS access to local filesystem via plugin?

Tags: javascript, yui, air, plugins

I have a javascript photo-organizer built on the YUI JS libs which can organize photos from many sites via REST api. I want to know if I can resuse any of this code to organize photos on the local filesystem.

I need a **cross-browser** (i.e. PC/Mac) solution to the following (in order of increasing privilege):

1. persistent file access to read/write local XML datafile (between sessions)
2. ability to manage large uploads of thumbnails to my server
3. FOLDER+file access to scan JPGs in a folder tree. permission granted by user via drag-drop
4. ability to execute local shell script to generate thumbnails

I've looked at the following and found some short-comings:

- BrowserPlus - no way to save access to local FS between sessions
- GoogleGears - local access to files via dialog box, only
- Adobe Air - is this a possible solution??? can I reuse my javascript?

Can someone tell me if this is possible in Air, or if there are any other plugin options/strategies?

NOTE: I could live with a download and install solution like Adobe Air, as long as I don't have to write both PC/Mac versions. Does that make it NOT a security hole?  Also, can I reuse my YUI/Javascript inside AdobeAir - or do I have to start from scratch?

tia, m.

Comment: This would constitute a huge security hole.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Air is a standalone runtime. It will let you do what you want, but it does not run inside Browser, and will instead require users to install application to their desktop first (though it is cross browser and cross-platform).

Flash (or Flex) plugin inside Browser may be able to do some of the things you want, but I doubt it will let you free reign on the local file system for managing photos. You will be able to store some persistent data in local shared objects (kind of like Cookies), but very little amounts.